# how to capture only the "csv" lines with 5 values

Tags: linux, awk, sed, csv

we want to capture only the "csv" lines  with 5 values
according to this rule

```
"","","","",""
```

example:

```
more conf.csv

"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.driver.memory",
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.cores"
"linux02","cluster26","api.executor.instances","2"

"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.driver.memory","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.cores","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.instances","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.memory","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.sql.shuffle.partitions","141"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.dynamicAllocation.enabled","true"

"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.driver.memory","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.memory"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.cores"
"linux02","cluster26","api.executor.instances","2"
```

expected output:

```
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.driver.memory","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.cores","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.instances","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.memory","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.sql.shuffle.partitions","141"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.dynamicAllocation.enabled","true"
```

Comment: what have you try so far ? do you have idea ? it look like a simple regex would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

`awk -F "," 'NF==5 {print $0}' conf.csv`

prints lines with 5 fields. However, the line:

```
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.driver.memory",
```

induce an error because there is a last comma that tricks *awk* into believing that there is a fifth field in the line.

Comment: Shorter: `awk -F, 'NF == 5'`

Comment: and to protect against empty fields: `awk -F, 'NF == 5 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "") next; print}' file`

Answer (score 1):

For proper CSV handling, a CSV parser:

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
  data = CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) {|row|
    if row.size == 5 and row.none? {|elem| elem.nil?}
      puts CSV.generate_line(row, :force_quotes=>true)
    end
  }
' conf.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E '(".+",){4}".+"' Csv.file
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.driver.memory","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.cores","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.instances","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.memory","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.sql.shuffle.partitions","141"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.dynamicAllocation.enabled","true"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.driver.memory","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.memory"
```

`-E` will make use of extended regexp you search 4 time for `".+",` and add one time for `".+"`. But still you should have provide a bit of what you've try.

**Note:** I've used `.+` to search for non empty string if you want line with 5 fields even empty one replace `+` by `*`:

```
grep -E '(".*",){4}".*"' Csv.file
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the data with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) as a header-less, ragged (varying number of fields per record), CSV file and outputting all records that have exactly five fields:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N --ragged filter 'NF == 5' file
linux02,cluster26,api2-thrift-apiconf,api.driver.memory,
linux02,cluster26,api2-thrift-apiconf,api.driver.memory,2
linux02,cluster26,api2-thrift-apiconf,api.executor.cores,2
linux02,cluster26,api2-thrift-apiconf,api.executor.instances,2
linux02,cluster26,api2-thrift-apiconf,api.executor.memory,2
linux02,cluster26,api2-thrift-apiconf,api.sql.shuffle.partitions,141
linux02,cluster26,api2-thrift-apiconf,api.dynamicAllocation.enabled,true
```

Note that we get an extra record compared to the expected output since the given input contains a record with an empty 5th field.

We may exclude records with an empty 5th field, and also force quoting of all fields, like so:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N --ragged --quote-all filter 'NF == 5 && !is_empty($5)' file
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.driver.memory","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.cores","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.instances","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.executor.memory","2"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.sql.shuffle.partitions","141"
"linux02","cluster26","api2-thrift-apiconf","api.dynamicAllocation.enabled","true"
```